# My two jQuery codes are conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not very good with JavaScript or jQuery. I have two different pieces of code, but the latter one seems to conflict the first.

My first code is to add a background color to my navigation on scroll:

```
jQuery(function () {

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(window).on("scroll",function(){

            if(jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 200)
                jQuery(".header").css({backgroundColor:"#4A6971"});
            else
                jQuery(".header").css({backgroundColor:"transparent"});

        })

    })

});
```

My second code is to trigger a fade in animation that I got from animate.css:

```
jQuery(function () {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop());
        var topDivHeight = jQuery(".showcase_div").height();
        var viewPortSize = jQuery(window).height();

        var triggerAt = 150;
        var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;

        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight) {
            jQuery('.pic1').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
            jQuery(this).off('scroll');
        }
    });

});
```

Why is the second code conflicting with the first one? The background color on my navigation does not appear anymore since I added the second code.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, please provide a working snippet. So we can see HTML/CSS, the action as well and better understand what's going on.

Comment: You should unbind the scroll event before doing the second scroll assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
jQuery(this).off('scroll');
```

[removes *all* event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/off/), that were registered via jQuery, including your first one. You have two options to mitigate that:

1. Name your second event handler function and remove it specifically:

   ```
   function foo() {
       // ...
       jQuery(this).off('scroll', foo /* <- same name as above */);
   }
   jQuery(window).scroll(foo);
   ```
2. or use [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/), which automatically deregisters itself after the first run:

   ```
   jQuery(window).one('scroll', function() {
       // ...
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much! The first option worked for me :) much appreciate it!